# react-native-video onEnd is called when video starts

Tags: react-native

When I `console.log()` inside the `onEnd` function of a video component, it gets called instantly on load of the page. The `console.log()` from the `onPress` of `ThouchableHighlight` is also called at the same time. I used `Actions.videoPlayer()` from the repo `react-native-router-flux` to go to this page on click of the thumbnail of this video.

```
render() {
let video = require('../videos/HISTORISCHETUIN.mp4');

 return (
  <View>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={console.log("Test")}>
      <View>
        <Video source={video}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
               ref={ref => this.player = ref} // Store reference
               rate={1.0}                     // 0 is paused, 1 is normal.
               volume={1.0}                   // 0 is muted, 1 is normal.
               muted={false}                  // Mutes the audio entirely.
               paused={true}                 // Pauses playback entirely.
               resizeMode="stretch"             // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.
               repeat={true}                  // Repeat forever.
               playInBackground={false}       // Audio continues to play when app entering background.
               playWhenInactive={false}       // [iOS] Video continues to play when control or notification center are shown.
               progressUpdateInterval={250.0} // [iOS] Interval to fire onProgress (default to ~250ms)
               onLoadStart={this.loadStart}   // Callback when video starts to load
               onLoad={() => {
                          this.player.seek(30);
                          }}      // Callback when video loads
               onProgress={this.setTime}      // Callback every ~250ms with currentTime
               onEnd={console.log("Test")}             // Callback when playback finishes
               onError={this.videoError}      // Callback when video cannot be loaded
               style={styles.video} />
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
)
```

}

Why doesn't it call `console.log()` after the video has ended? And when I press on the video it doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because you need to wrap it in a closure.

This code:

```
onEnd={console.log('123')}
```

Will immediately execute the `console.log` when the component is rendered, when the prop is actually expecting a function.

To fix it, use:

```
onEnd={() => console.log('123')}
```

Here you're giving the prop a function it can execute, rather than the result of `console.log`.