# react native video stops right away

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-video

When I try playing a live stream de player stops right away.
From logs I see that onEnd si called as soon as the video starts.

The weird thing is that it only happens on an actual phone, it works fine on emulators. Tried with Android Studio Emulator and Genymotion, both work fine. 
Both debug and release fail playing live stream on actual phones.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={VideoPlayerStyles.fullScreen} onPress={this.handleVideoTap}>
  <Video source={{ uri: this.props.channelSrc }}
    style={VideoPlayerStyles.fullScreen}
    rate={this.state.rate}
    paused={this.state.paused}
    volume={this.state.volume}
    muted={this.state.muted}
    resizeMode={this.state.resizeMode}
    onLoad={this.onLoad}
    onProgress={this.onProgress}
    onEnd={this.onEnd}
    repeat={false}
    fullscreen={true}
    ref={ref => {
        this.player = ref
    }}
      onBuffer={this.onBuffer} 
    onError={this.videoError} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Is your video URL (this.props.channelSrc) accessible from Mobile network?

Comment: do you see any debug info in Android Studio when the playback fails? Also, does it do this for all videos (can you try another URL)?

Comment: It only does it for live stream, for movies it works fine. There are no errors just the video is at most an second long. Tried with rn-fetch-blob and the video was about 20—30 seconds long. Also link works fine with react native vlc.

Comment: can you share the streaming link?

Comment: @Gowtham any IPTV live stream has the same issue, I could share but in private.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Video URI is accessible from your device.

You may be trying to access URI which is accessible from Emulator running on a desktop/laptop, as the desktop/laptop and emulator will be connected to same network.

Open Chrome on mobile device and try to access the Video URI. If it does not work, then its network issue.

Comment: It is, I tested with the direct url instead of props a. Also it works fine on emulator, movies work fine. It's just live stream that stops as soon as it begins.
I tried with native vlc player and link works fine however the player is outdated and down the line it gives way more errors, even compiling ones.

Answer (score 0):

According to

> ***Tom Walters***

answer

> [react-native-video onEnd is called when video starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911993/react-native-video-onend-is-called-when-video-starts)

```
onEnd={this.onEnd}
```

to 
Will immediately execute the `console.log` when the component is rendered, when the prop is actually expecting a function.

To fix it, use:

```
onEnd={() => this.onEnd}
```

Comment: That's just a binding issue, not really the issue I'm having.